# How to detect in LMC that calculation is greater than 999 and then output 999?

Tags: computer-science, little-man-computer

I need to write an LMC program to solve a+bx+x<sup>2</sup>. Further, if the result is greater than 999, then it needs to output 999; if less than 999, then output the result.

I have done the a+bx+x<sup>2</sup> part, but have no idea how to output 999 when there is overflow.

Here is my code:

```
          IN
          STO a
          IN
          STO b
          IN 
          STO x
          LDA x
          STO x2
bx        LDA x
          BRZ end
          SUB one
          STO x
          LDA ans
          ADD b
          STO ans
          BR   bx
end       LDA ans
          LDA x2
          STO y
xx        LDA y
          BRZ END
          SUB ONE
          STO y
          LDA ANS
          ADD x2
          STO ANS
          BR   xx
END       LDA ANS
          ADD a
          STO ANS
          LDA ANS
          ADD ans
          SUB z
          BRP postive
          LDA ANS
          OUT
          HLT
postive   LDA z
          OUT
          HLT
a         DAT 000
b         DAT 000
x         DAT 000
x2        DAT 000
y         DAT 000
z         DAT 999
one       DAT 001
ONE       DAT 001
ans       DAT 000
ANS       DAT 000
```

Comment: Could you give some feedback to the answer(s) below?

Comment: Hello, did you have time to look at the answer? Or are you no longer interested?

Answer (score 0):

You did well on the calculation, and it is indeed difficult to detect overflow (more than 999) because typically an LMC accumulator cannot store greater values, and the accumulator's value is not defined (in the specification) when such overflow happens, nor is it specified whether the "negative" flag will be set. So there is really nothing we can use to detect such overflow which would be compatible on all LMC emulators.

The trick is to calculate the expression as 999 − ( −  − ²) and detect *negative overflow* (below 0), for which we have the `BRP` instruction. If there is no negative overflow, we can inverse that result again as 999 − (999 − ( −  − ²)) is the same as  −  − ². So that means you would load 999 into `ans` and then instead of `ADD` you would use `SUB`, and after each `SUB` you would check whether there is negative overflow, and if so go to the block that will output 999.

#### Some other remarks

- Don't use labels which are the same except for their capitalisation. Not all LMC emulators are case sensitive.
- You don't need two `ONE` nor two `ANS` data fields.
- It is best practice to explicitly initialise `ans` at the start of the code and not rely on the fact that you have `ans DAT 0`. This is because an LMC has a *reset* functionality, which will *not* reset the data, but only set the program counter back to the top. This would lead to wrong results.
- Your logic for multiplication is correct, but you could reuse the same code for calculation of both  and ²: realise that this expression is equivalent to ( + ), and so you could add (subtract) both  and  to the result in each iteration of the loop, and so perform one multiplication!

Here is the corrected and reduced code:

```html
#input:1 2 3
         INP
         STA a
         INP
         STA b
         INP
         STA x
         STA x2
         LDA z # "inverse" ans
         SUB a # do this first
loop     STA ans
         LDA x
         BRZ output
         SUB one
         STA x
         LDA ans
         SUB x2  # subtract both x...
         BRP continue
         BRA overflow
continue SUB b   # ... and b
         BRP loop

overflow LDA zero  # prepare for outputing 999 (overflow)
         STA ans
output   LDA z
         SUB ans # 999 - (999 - (a + bx + x^2))
         OUT
         HLT

a        DAT 0
b        DAT 0
x        DAT 0
x2       DAT 0
z        DAT 999
ans      DAT 0

zero     DAT 0
one      DAT 1




<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/trincot/lmc@v0.816/lmc.js"></script>
```

You can run the code in this snippet. The default input has been set to 1 2 3, but you can change the input interactively.

Comment: A small question, is underflow the right word here? I think this is still overflow, even though it was in the negative direction.

Comment: Yes, that is a matter of definition. I just wanted to make the distinction with the overflow where it is greater than 999.

Comment: fair, would 'negative overflow' be helpful here then?

Comment: That is indeed helpful. Updated. Thanks!